# setting the target database version for mysql workbench migration

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running a migration from sql server to mariadb 10.0 and the generated code keeps failing due to a syntax error in the create table statements.

Specifcally it doesn't like the `INDEX` lines of the create table statements. And example of a statement it chokes on is

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  `fk_manager` varchar(255),
  INDEX `imgr` (`fk_manager` ASC) visible
);
```

This is the error I get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX 
`imgr` (`fk_manager` ASC) visible)' 
at line 3
```

If i remove the `visible` keyword the same command works, so I assume this is syntax valid on newer versions of mysql but not mine. Is there any way I can tell mysql workbench to exclude it?

Answer (score 3):

In the top menu click Model > Model Options

In the dialogue that pops up, select MySQL on the left side

Change `Target MySQL Version` to 5.7